# Breaking for or loop GWT callback response

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I want to **break the for loop** in **GWT callback's execute method response**.

For Example,

```
for (int idx = 0; idx < recordList.getLength(); idx++) {  //Starting ABC FOR LOOP
    ABCDMI.addData(recordList.get(idx), 
                   new DSCallback() {       
                       public void execute(DSResponse response, Object rawData, DSRequest request) {      
                            if(response.getAttribute("UnSuccess") != null && !response.getAttribute("UnSuccess").equalsIgnoreCase("")) {    
                                 break;  //I want to break ABC FOR LOOP here.   
                            }
                   }
}
```

Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: You can't break from anonymous class declaration, because `execute` method is only *declared* there. What are you trying to achieve? Sorry, my answer totally missed this point.

Comment: I am doing updation of multiple records but if any record is not added/updated successfully then don't want to continue with for loop. So I want to put break statement over there.

Comment: Currently records are processed asynchronously. It might be the case that record #10 is processed before record #3. To break on first unsuccessful record you should implement sequential processing, e.g. add record, wait for execution, process next record, etc.

Comment: @defaultlocale : You are right. I will look into it.

Comment: Check out the comment to my answer and consider using Manolo's code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call an asynchronous method, you dont know how long it will take. In your examples all of these calls will be sent in almost the same instant, but the response would come in any time in the future, so the order is not guaranteed.

Of-course you cannot break a loop inside your callback, but you can handle the loop inside your callback calling the async method from it each time one call finishes.

This example should work in your case, and all callbacks would be executed sequentially.

```java
DSCallback myCallBack = new DSCallback() {
  int idx = 0; 
  int length = recordList.getLength();

  public void execute(DSResponse response, Object rawData, DSRequest request) {
    if (++idx < length 
          && (response.getAttribute("UnSuccess") == null 
            || !response.getAttribute("UnSuccess").equalsIgnoreCase(""))) {
      ABCDMI.addData(recordList.get(idx), this);
    }
  }
};

ABCDMI.addData(recordList.get(0), myCallBack);
```